# Mysql REPLACE and Delete old entry

Tags: php, mysql, replace

I have a table with 57k entries with column comp_phone (UNIQUE KEY `Phone` (`comp_phone`)) now i am try to time this column with

```
update uk_data set comp_phone= REPLACE(comp_phone,'  ',' ')
```

but because i have UNIQUE KEY on this column i am getting error

```
[SQL] update uk_data set comp_phone= REPLACE(comp_phone,'  ',' ')

[Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry '01268 203***' for key 'Phone'
```

so i am using

```
DELETE FROM uk_data WHERE comp_phone = '01268 203***'
```

to delete old row. but this is taking very long because i don't know how many rows gets duplicate after REPLACE so is there a easy way to REPLACE and delete or overwrite old entry

Thx

Comment: Is 'time' a euphemism for 'edit'!?!?!

Comment: You defined a unique key because you don't want duplicate keys. Now your UPDATE statement generates duplicate key and you are looking for a way to ignore this error? That doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: @ZombieHunter yes ... this is happening because some of the numbers are stored with <space> and now i want to remove the <space> like 01268 203000<space> and i already have one with no space 01268 203000, there i am facing the problem

Comment: @Harinder did you check my ans

Comment: @Harinder review updated answer without while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this query

```
CREATE TEMPORARY table Kratika
(
    _id int,
    _value varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO Kratika
SELECT 1, '1111222255' UNION 
SELECT 2, '1111222 255' UNION -- duplicate
SELECT 3, '11112222 55' UNION -- duplicate
SELECT 4, '1111222233'; -- not duplicate

SELECT * FROM Kratika;

DELETE FROM Kratika WHERE _value <> REPLACE(_value, ' ', '') ;

SELECT * FROM Kratika;
```

**Output**

```
1   1111222255
2   1111222 255
3   11112222 55
4   1111222233

-- Select after deletion of duplicate records
    1   1111222255
    4   1111222233
```

**Edited**

If you are ok with while loop then you could test this (I am not a MySQL developer, I don't know why MySQL not allowing me to write while loop, so created proc for the same)

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_kratik;
delimiter ##

CREATE PROCEDURE test_kratik
(

)
BEGIN
DROP table IF EXISTS Kratika;
CREATE TEMPORARY table Kratika
(
    _id int,
    _value varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO Kratika
SELECT 1, '1111222255' UNION 
SELECT 2, '1111222 255' UNION -- duplicate
SELECT 3, '11112222 55' UNION -- duplicate
SELECT 4, '1111222233'; -- not duplicate

SELECT * FROM Kratika;

SET @ID := 0;
SET @DUP_ID := 0;
SET @value := '';

WHILE @ID <= (SELECT MAX(_id) FROM kratika) DO
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT _id from kratika WHERE _id = @ID) THEN
            BEGIN
                SET @value = (SELECT REPLACE(_value, ' ', '') from kratika WHERE _id = @ID);
                DELETE FROM kratika
                WHERE REPLACE(_value, ' ', '') = @value
                AND _id <> @ID;
            END;
        END IF;
        SET @ID = @ID + 1;
    END;
END WHILE;

UPDATE kratika
SET _value = REPLACE(_value, ' ', '') 
WHERE _value <> REPLACE(_value, ' ', '') ;

SELECT * FROM kratika;

END ##

delimiter ;

CALL test_kratik();
```

**Updated** *It would be fine if you don't want to use while loop....*

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Kratika; 

CREATE TEMPORARY table Kratika
(
    _id int,
    _value varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO Kratika
SELECT 1, '1111222255' UNION 
SELECT 2, '1111222 255' UNION -- duplicate
SELECT 3, '11112222 55' UNION -- duplicate
SELECT 4, '111122 2233'; -- not duplicate

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS copy_temp; 

CREATE TEMPORARY table copy_temp  
(
    _id1 int,
    _value1 varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO copy_temp
SELECT _id, _value FROM kratika;

SELECT * FROM Kratika;

DELETE FROM Kratika 
WHERE _id <> (SELECT _id1 FROM copy_temp 
WHERE REPLACE(_value, ' ', '') = REPLACE(_value1, ' ', '') 
Limit 1
);

UPDATE kratika
SET _value = REPLACE(_value, ' ', '') 
WHERE _value <> REPLACE(_value, ' ', '') ;


SELECT * FROM Kratika;
```

**Output**

```
1   1111222255
2   1111222 255
3   11112222 55
4   1111222233
```

**After Update**

```
1   1111222255
4   1111222233
```

Comment: this will delete all rows which get edited no mater if its duplicate or not .... ;(

Comment: @Harinder if 4th entry is `4   111122 2233`, then it will delete that also right. so you want to retain it with `1111222233` right?

Comment: in place of 4th entry if u place 11112222 33 with space it will delete it because query will delete all thing with space

Comment: Are you ok with `while` or `for loop`?

Comment: i can do with php but want to do this on mysql server so need something for that ;(

Comment: with php i have alternative but i am looking for mysql ...thx any way